# Connecting a MongoDB serverless database to Mongo Charts

Tags: database, mongodb, charts, nosql, mongodb-charts

I want to connect a serverless MongoDB instance to MongoDB charts.

I don't see any of my serverless instances when I try to add data sources on my Mongo Chart dashboard.

If this is not possible, would somebody know if there is a way of upgrading a serverless instance to a dedicated one? Apart from running a script, and creating a new instance.

Note: I am not very optimistic on the last question, since of course the underlying data probably needs to go from one server to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Serverless Instance Limitations doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/), this is unfortunately not possible.

As for the second part of your question, the answer is also negative, but apparently there's a room for optimism - this feature is marked as 'coming soon'.